# Show modal on load only once

Tags: jquery

I have a page that shows a modal dialog onload. There's a checkbox that user needs to check and submit (think Terms of Use) before the modal is dismissed. Once that happens the page can be reloaded again, but the dialog box should never come back. Originally I thought of using PHP session but I want to dismiss the dialog box with JS (jQuery) without reloading the page. What is an alternative? Can I use cookies for the duration of the session?

My current code looks like this:

JS:

```
$(document).delegate('#myButton', 'click', function() {

     if ($('input[name="myCheckbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        $('#myDialog').remove();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDialog">
   text
   <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox"> <input id="myButton" type="button" value="click me">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either localStorage permanently or sessionStorage just for one session

```
 localStorage.setItem('showModal',true);
 localStorage.getItem('showModal');
```

and it's pure javascript. No need to do it on the server side.

Comment: Hmm, I've never used that... I think this is exctly what I was looking for. So, I add this to the click function and the wrap my onload modal function with condition -- if true?..

Comment: yep. In onload just check whether the user has already checked the checkbox or not via localStorage.getItem

Comment: Keep browser support in mind.  Right now IE is the most problematic.  Requires 8+.  http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

Comment: Gotta love that IE... So what are the alternatives?

Comment: on the client side only cookies

Comment: cookies seem so convoluted. I just need it till the browser is closed, how do I do that with cookies? And I certainly rather limit the number of plugins I have to use. I try to stick only with those that i can constantly reuse, not once.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1){

    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
    var year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
  }
});
```